# How to check for empty file in the folder?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code which updates SQL database using the files in a folder and delete them after update but its giving me an exception whenever the blank file is found in the folder. It gives error " The object reference not set to Instance of an object" . What i really want to do is before processing each file i need to check each file if its blank then delete it otherwise process it. this is the code :

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Dim dirinfo5 As DirectoryInfo
        Dim allFiles5() As FileInfo
        dirinfo5 = New DirectoryInfo("E:\UPDATE\")
        allFiles5 = dirinfo5.GetFiles("*.csv")
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        If allFiles5.Length <> 0 Then
            Try
                For Each fl5 As FileInfo In allFiles5
                    'MsgBox(fl.FullName.ToString())
                    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SQL_con2)
                    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fl5.FullName)
                    Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
                    Dim value() As String = line.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(44))
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                    Dim row As DataRow
                    For Each dc As String In value
                        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dc))
                    Next

                    While Not sr.EndOfStream
                        value = sr.ReadLine.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(44))
                        If (value.Length = dt.Columns.Count) Then
                            row = dt.NewRow
                            row.ItemArray = value
                            dt.Rows.Add(row)
                        End If

                    End While
                    Dim bc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "[DB].[dbo].[LData]"
                    bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count
                    con.Open()
                    bc.WriteToServer(dt)
                    bc.Close()
                    con.Close()
                    sr.Close()
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fl5.FullName)
                    sr.Dispose()
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method: it returns a `String` so you can check its .`Length`.